# How to delete a vector without importing any library

Tags: c++, string, pointers, vector

```
vector<char*> x;
```

I have many vectors in my code. However, I need to delete them to minimize memory usage. I know there is a solution like using a  "shared_array" but I am not permitted to import any other library. Is there any good solution to prevent memory leak after using vectors?

Comment: vector<unique_ptr<char>> x; and when your done using the vector, x.clear();

Comment: Just manually delete them when you're done with them? Or write your own `shared_ptr` class?

Comment: @johnathon: why don't you post that as answer?

Answer (score 3):

In your code snippet, you are using a vector of char pointers. I assume that those pointers are allocated via new, and they need to be freed via delete. If the vector goes out of scope, it will be freed, but all those char arrays won't get freed. You need to free them manually.

An alternative would be to use [`std::string`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/), specifically `vector<std::string>`. In this way, when the vector goes out of scope, all the strings will be automatically deleted.

Comment: what if OP was using the char* to represent something that isn't exactly a string ... say ... packets from a TCP connection? vector<char> is best used in that case, either way i agree, owning pointers are bad, but if one must, it's better to use a smart pointer.

Comment: why would char* be 'best' to represent TCP packets? Totally depends on the situation.. One could have a class to represent the packages herevy removing the need to manually manage their memory

Comment: I used the simpler assumption: that he was using strings and not something else. In that case he can just iterate trough the vector and `delete[]` all its members. The `vector` can clean up after itself, but if you're using plain old pointers, the vector won't clean them up for you. You have to delete them yourself.

Comment: @johnathon, `std::string` can be used to store binary data as well. Unlike C strings, `0` can be stored in C++ `std::string`s.

Comment: @bdonlan  i use vector<char> for any network traffic that has a binary format header, such as the YMSG protocol of yahoo. Besides, really, whats the advantage of using std::string for this work anyways, nothing, and changing containers in the std is something that's trivial anyways. The only advantage i could for see, is using regex to parse the incoming string data of the packet it's self, as this would potentially incur an extra copy.  IMHO though a vector<char> is much easier to reason about, compared to a string for such usage.

Comment: @stijn if the characteristics of the packets varied from type of packet on the overlying protocol, varying in length in a unknowing sequence, then how could only a single class represent a packet built on top of the tcp protocol, especially if the packet it's self contained a mixture of binary data , and string data. Don't get me wrong, it could easily be done, however the benefits of simplistic usage would be far overshadowed by the incurring copy operations from a variable length buffer to the objects in question.

Comment: @stijn also to note, i don't use a vector<char> to represent the packets, i merely use it as the buffer for incoming data. And use a struct to represent the binary data to easily extract out the fields of the header, such as length , and service type. This allows me to easily extract the packet from the buffer, and clear that packet as a whole from the buffer.

Comment: @johnathon, there's really not much difference. on some C++ implementations `std::string` might support copy-on-write, which might be handy at times, and might also support zero-copy substring. But from what I hear COW support is rare these days.

Comment: @bdonlan true, however each container has it's strengths and weaknesses, could be that I'm just more fond of vectors, particularly in the realm of buffers, and c api's. As in why call c_str() on a string object when you can just pass a reference to the first element of a vector. Same could be done with a string. Just all depends on what I'm trying to accomplish as to which container i choose to use.

Answer (score 2):

C++11 has support for smart pointer objects, such as `shared_ptr`, so you don't have to use Boost (or anything else).

As johnathon said, you can then just wrap the `char *` with a smart pointer et voilà, you don't have to worry about it anymore.

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<char*>> x;
```

or

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<char*>> x;
```

When the element is removed from the vector in either way (`.delete()`, `.erase()`, ...) or simply when vector is destroyed, you buffers will be freed.

If your STL implementation or compiler does not support this C++11 feature yet, you can also roll your own smart pointer type, it shouldn't be too hard. See for example [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15351/Implementing-a-simple-smart-pointer-in-c).

Comment: I like the link except for the fact that they use `void main`.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
//Create
vector<char*>* _vec = new vector<char*>(5);
//Fill with something
for(unsigned int i=0; i<_vec->size(); ++i)
    (*_vec)[i] = new char[100];
....

//Delete
for(unsigned int i=0; i<_vec->size(); ++i)
    delete[] (*_vec)[i]; //Deleting array of char
delete _vec; //but not delete[] as we deleting only one instance of vector
```

Comment: Well, of course he can, but why would he with all the benefits that RAII provides. This is a C way to do it.

Comment: This example is to understand how to perform it manualy. Of cource we should not use raw pointers it may be better `shared_ptr<vector<vector<char> > >` for example